# what does "first of all more" mean?

Tags: meaning

"first of all" could be used to indicate the first part of a sequence of steps.

It sound like the tutorial is [saying](https://youtu.be/3P49hWpNIzA?t=209)

> first of all more line them up

what does **more** mean here?

Comment: I think he says "first of all **imma** line 'em up"; where "imma" (or "ima", "i'ma" etc) is a colloquial / dialectal contraction of "I'm going to" or "I'm about to". However, I'm not entirely sure.  As per my comment on the previous question about this video - it's not a local accent to me.  I would expect "imma" to end with a schwa, but he does use the vowel sound of "more" so I can see why you heard that.  Not sure if that's a feature of his accent or if I'm misheading.

Comment: Yes, I hear /əməh/ and interpret it as *“I’m a”* as in *“I’m a gonna miss ya darlin’.”* (I’m going to miss you darling.) This is often written as “Imma” too (although personally that orthography confuses me because I wrongly read it as rhyming with “glimmer”). I good place to hear this in popular culture is the Black Eyed Peas song “Imma be.”  There is a good relevant discussion here: https://literalminded.wordpress.com/2010/04/25/thoughts-on-imma/

Comment: @stevekeiretsu Thank you so much. Would you please move your comments to answer? 
I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think he says "first of all **imma** line 'em up"; where "imma" (which may be variously transcribed "ima", "i'ma" etc) is a colloquial / dialectal contraction of "I'm going to" or "I'm about to". However, I'm not entirely sure. As per my comment on the previous question about this video - it's not a local accent to me. I would expect "imma" to end with a schwa, but he does use the same vowel sound as in "more", so I can understand why you heard that.  I was not sure if that's a feature of his accent or if I was  misheading, but at least one other commenter seems to agree it's "imma", so I shall post this as an answer as requested.